# How to bind a v-model with nested object?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm experiencing something I absolutely do not understand: I have a form and it turns out that two fields that are supposed to be independent are synched. If the user enters something in field A, it is also displayed immediately in field B. This would make sense, if the two fields are bound to the same model, but there are not - at least not intentionally.

Here is a simplified representation of my reactive data:

```
export default class ContractDetails extends Vue {

  (...)

  contract: Contract= {
    compagny: {
      name: '',
      contactSale: {
        name: '', // this feld is synch with...
        tel: '',
        mail: ''
      },
    },
    contactCustomer: {
      name: '', // ...this one
      tel: '',
      mail: ''
    },
    notices: ''
  }
```

Here is how I do the binding in the form:

```
 <q-input v-model="contract.contactCustomer.name"
                         outlined :readonly="!isEditable()"
                         :rules="rulePflichtfeldMitMax1024Zeichen"
                         label="Name *"/>

<q-input v-model="contract.compagny.contactSale.name"
                         outlined :readonly="!isEditable()"
                         :rules="rulePflichtfeldMitMax1024Zeichen"
                         label="Name *"/>
```

And here are the Typescript interfaces I defined:

```
export default interface Contract{
  compagny: Company;
  contactCustomer: ContactPerson;
  notices: string
}

export interface Company{
  name: string;
  contactSale: ContactPerson;
}

export default interface ContactPerson{
  name: string;
  tel: string;
  mail: string;
}
```

Do you have any explanations for that behavior?

Comment: Could be a miss type in your after logic? Some validation that you are trying to do but instead of === you have = ?